# how to add a "North Arrow" on a geopandas map

Tags: python, geopandas

I created a map using geopandas, but I am unable to add a "North Arrow" on the map.

After creating the map, I have tried to add the "north arrow" using matplotlib.image module and tried different ways (see example below) but none of them provided a good result. I am looking for better code that can add a good "North Arrow to the map"

```
import matplotlib.image as img

from matplotlib.offsetbox import TextArea, DrawingArea, OffsetImage, 
    AnnotationBbox

im=img.imread(r'C:\Users\jnisengw\Dropbox\2019\Data 
    Science\QGIS\north_arrow1.png')

imagebox = OffsetImage(im,zoom=0.27)

ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, (598500,4699000))

ax.add_artist(ab)
```

Comment: We can't see your image. You need to post the image here (not a third-party link, Dropbox, etc.)

Comment: similar technique as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458251/plot-over-an-image-background-in-python/34459284#34459284

Comment: https://www.net-analysis.com/blog/cartopylayout.html

Answer (score 11):

If you only need to add a simple arrow, you can also consider the `annotate()` [method](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/annotations.html).

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('nybb'))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
gdf.plot(ax=ax)

x, y, arrow_length = 0.5, 0.5, 0.1
ax.annotate('N', xy=(x, y), xytext=(x, y-arrow_length),
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', width=5, headwidth=15),
            ha='center', va='center', fontsize=20,
            xycoords=ax.transAxes)
```

[image]

Notes: When you pass `xycoords=ax.transAxes`, the x, y coordinate is normalized, and `x, y = 0.5, 0.5` means you put the arrowhead in the middle of your map.

Comment: Will this respect the map projection though? I suppose only if xycoords is set to 'data'.

Comment: `xycoords` only affects the position of the arrow and does not interact with the shape data. I believe if you use a cylindrical projection, north will remain north, regardless of CRS. However, if you rotate the map, of course, this is no longer the case.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody still needs this...
[EOmaps v3.1](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) now has a proper north-arrow and interacts nicely with geopandas!

```
from eomaps import Maps
m = Maps()
m.add_feature.preset.ocean()
m.add_compass(style="north arrow")
```

[image: EOmaps - compass]

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is create a Polygon, and plot it into your matplotlib `ax` (there are some other solutions like this in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55522395/1910555) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26935798/1910555)).

The [`geo_northarrow`](https://github.com/pmdscully/geo_northarrow) library (GNUv3) does this by plotting the north arrow polygons to the matplotlib axes.

```
import geopandas
import geodatasets
from geo_northarrow import add_north_arrow

chicago = geopandas.read_file(geodatasets.get_path("geoda.chicago_commpop"))
groceries = geopandas.read_file(geodatasets.get_path("geoda.groceries"))
display(chicago.head())
ax = chicago.plot(column="POP2010");

add_north_arrow(ax, scale=.75, xlim_pos=.9025, ylim_pos=.965, color='#000', text_scaler=4, text_yT=-1.25)
```

[image]

* *NB: Limitation - This library is only suitable for maps with `north-south axis` alignment exactly to the `y-axis`; as it lacks a north-orientation lookup and rotation.*