# Why is Shapely plotting two lines when I change a coordinate?

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapely

I'm trying to understand how Shapely works.

I can draw a simple line with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = Point(0,0)
B = Point(1,1)
AB = LineString([A,B])

plt.plot(AB)
```

However when I alter the coordinates:

```
A = Point(1,0)
B = Point(3,4)
AB = LineString([A,B])

plt.plot(AB)
```

Shapely decides to plot two lines, which is behaviour I don't understand.

Using Shapely 1.7.0

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Related: [How do I plot Shapely polygons and objects using Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55522395/7851470)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `plt.plot()` incorrectly.

What `plt.plot()` does is [Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib-pyplot-plot)

In the docs, you can see that since the call `plot(AB)` has only 1 argument, `AB` is being passed as the Y values.
The X value, in this case, is the index of the elements in the array of Y values.

It is the same as calling `plt.plot([(1,0),(3,4)])`. Since you have 2 tuples of Y values, you will get 2 different lines: `[(0,1),(1,3)]` and `[(0,0),(1,4)]`. (Notice the x values are 0 and 1, the index of the corresponding tuple of Y value.)

You can see in the screenshot of the output, that in the first case you also plot 2 lines. But in the case of these specific values, `plt.plot([(0,0),(1,1)])` will plot the same line twice.

If you just want to graph a line from point A to point B, you can use:

```
A = Point(1,0)
B = Point(3,4)
AB = LineString([A,B])

plt.plot(*AB.xy)

plt.show()
```