# How do I plot a polygon from a list of tuples using Shapely package

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapely

I tried it but I keep getting an error.
Below is the code I use to plot:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


polygon1 = Polygon([(0,5),
                    (1,1),
                    (3,0),
                    ])

plt.plot(polygon1)
plt.show()
```

However, I keep getting a `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Polygon'` when calling `plt.plot(polygon1)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I plot Shapely polygons and objects using Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522395/how-do-i-plot-shapely-polygons-and-objects-using-matplotlib)

Comment: Interestingly enough, the code in the question is the exact copy of the code from the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib cannot understand `Polygon`, you need to pass the polygon vertices in matplotlib `plot`.

Below code works:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

polygon1 = Polygon([(0,5),
                    (1,1),
                    (3,0)])

x,y = polygon1.exterior.xy
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: Also, consider copy-pasting the error instead of adding a screen shot.

Comment: It worked. I get it now. The plot function expects (x,y) parameters